# How to use flow_from_dataframe with compute_class_weight?

Tags: pandas, keras, scikit-learn

I want to validation classes weights adjustment but it show AttributeError: 'DataFrameIterator' object has no attribute 'shape'. I don't know how to fix this but I saw weight_col=None in the argument of flow_from_dataframe you can read in this [document](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/) Not sure if the same or not?

[image]